# Turning Off Blender 2.82 VSE Cache Indicator

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor, cache

So I've finally made the switch to the Blender 2.8 series.

In the VSE the new visual indication of cached frames is *nice*, however I find it to be quite distracting.

[image: Blender 2.82 VSE panel showing cached frame indicator at the bottom]

Is there any way in which I can disable or otherwise make invisible this indicator?  It is unnecessary for my workflow and is somewhat distracting.

Answer (score 1):

I'll facepalm myself here.  Of course it's in the menu system.  View|Cache|View Cache:

[image: VSE Menu detail: View|Cache|View Cache]

Turning off the checkbox removed it from the view.

Comment: In the sidebar, you can disable caching and in the Preview sidebar you can switch on/off the prefetch cache function(it'll only work if the main cache render is checked, tho). You should grab the latest 2.83 beta for an improved cache function.

Comment: @tintwotin:  Thanks for the tip, and I had already done that as part of my workflow.  I primarily use Blender for video editing—my workflow normalizes and proxies ingested footage prior to assembly in the VSE.  In my use case the cache is redundant.